Unbearably slow iCloud sync, serious problem (fileproviderd)
Hope to find some help here...
Problem:
I have been unable to sync iCloud files for the past 3 days now (Sonoma 14.5, M1 Mini 2020). It is unbearably slow.
I tried to disable sync from System Preferences, did many restarts - nothing helps (all the stuff that is typically suggest as in here).
In Console I see hundreds of errors about some SQL statement that is "significantly too slow":
[ERR 2024-07-13 08:41:13.922+0200] fileproviderd[661] com.apple.CloudDocs.iCloudDriveFileProvider/7{34}4  Significantly too slow SQL statement

See screenshot here
This how it looks like in the finder

The indicator changes verrrrry slowly (last digit counts up maybe once per minute.)
Someone having similar issues and knows how to resolve?
Thank you!

You could try fully signing out of iCloud, rebooting, then signing back in

Could be cache corruption. Start in safe mode and test, then restart as usual and test again.

Thanks @KevinGrabher, tried this. Everything got deleted and is being re-synced, just exactly as slow as before. "brctl log -ws --shorten | grep slow" still gives me tons of [ERR] Significantly too slow SQL statement: UPDATE FS_snapshot

Thanks @LincD. Tried this as well, no difference (same in Safe Mode).

fileproviderd maintains an SQLite database at this location: ~/Library/Application Support/FileProvider/*/database where * is a long hexadecimal string. Inside that folder are files named db, db-shm, and db-wal. I suggest these steps: (1) Delete db-shm and db-wal. (2) Force-quit fileproviderd in Activity Monitor or in the shell. It should restart immediately. The files you deleted will be recreated automatically. Test. If there's no improvement, disable iCloud Drive and all third-party cloud sync services, if any. Delete db, restart fileproviderd, and then re-enable iCloud Drive.

Thanks @LincD. This is something I haven't tried yet, but I will. Just one thing: I see that I have MULTIPLE folders named after hex strings. Three to be exact. All of them have the mentioned db* folders in it. Their modification date is different (two from August and one from July, yesterday). Which is the correct one or should I delete all? Thanks again!

@LincD. I just tried with the most recent folder and deleted the suggested files. I cannot believe it, but now syncing indeed looks different and more "alive", meaning different sync numbers are displayed and syncing actually seems to take place. I have to say thank you for now. Looking promising.

fileproviderd maintains an SQLite database at this location:
~/Library/Application Support/FileProvider/*/database

where * is a long hexadecimal string (a unique identifier). There may be more than one such folder with different identifiers; in that case, only the one with the most recent modification date is in use.
Inside the database folder are files named db, db-shm, and db-wal. The first one contains the actual database, and the others are caches.
Step 1
Delete db-shm and db-wal. Force-quit fileproviderd in Activity Monitor or in the shell. It should restart immediately. The cache files you deleted will be recreated, perhaps after a delay. Test. If there's no improvement, continue.
Step 2
Disable iCloud Drive and all third-party cloud file-sync services, if any. Delete db, restart fileproviderd, and then re-enable iCloud Drive. The database will be rebuilt from scratch.


There may be more than one such folder with different identifiers; in that case, only the one with the most recent modification date is in use.

In my case, I had three folders. The database folder in the oldest one was empty. But the database in other two was not empty and both were being used. I had to clear out database in both folders to force database rebuild.
